# XSLT - How to Loop over XML repeating/duplicated nodes and get the first Occurence

Tags: html, css, for-loop, xslt, iteration

I have the following problem (which is quite often discussed on this domain but still I can't get the exact solution):
I have an XML like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S001_subs_block>
  <BS0900_summary_block>
      <BS09001>
        <details>
          <descr_en>Services Monthly Fee</descr_en>
          <Amt>10.00</Amt>
        </details>
        <details>
          <descr_en>Calls</descr_en>
          <Amt>5.00</Amt>
        </details>
        <details>
          <descr_en>*International Roaming</descr_en>
          <Amt>7.00</Amt>
        </details>
      </BS09001>
</S001_subs_block>
<S001_subs_block>
  <BS0900_summary_block>
      <BS09001>
        <details>
          <descr_en>Services Monthly Fee</descr_en>
          <Amt>8.00</Amt>
        </details>
        <details>
          <descr_en>Calls</descr_en>
          <Amt>9.00</Amt>
        </details>
        <details>
          <descr_en>*International Roaming</descr_en>
          <Amt>14.00</Amt>
        </details>
      </BS09001>
</S001_subs_block>
```

What I need is to show the HTML output only for the first repeated cycle children values and put it in a table.
My XSLT Attempt was:

```
<table class="zui-table zui-table-rounded">
        <tr>
           <th>Subscriber Invoice Summary</th>
        </tr>

       <xsl:for-each select="//BS09001/details">
       <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="descr_en"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Amt"/></td>
        </tr>
       </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>

       <xsl:for-each select="//BS09002/details">
       <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="descr_en"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Amt"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>

      </table>
```

This is not working, I want the HTML table to display only the first occurence of values, that is:

```
<table class="zui-table zui-table-rounded">
<tr>
<th>Account Invoice Summary</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Services Monthly Fee</td><td>10.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Calls</td><td>5.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>*International Roaming</td><td>14.00</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I don't need the HTML Code, I need the XSLT to select only the first repeated cycle values and in case the possibility to go over multiple repeated cycle having the control of Iteration number.
Hope I was clear :-(

Comment: Use `<xsl:for-each select="//BS09001/details[1]">` to get first entry details and remove the `xsl:if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get what you're after. A quick search hit upon this SO answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15693824) that uses Muenchian Grouping to do what (I believe) you want. Adapted for your purposes it looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:key name="details" match="//BS0900_summary_block/*" use="local-name()" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table class="zui-table zui-table-rounded">
        <tr>
            <th>Account Invoice Summary</th>
        </tr>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="//BS0900_summary_block/*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('details', local-name())[1])]/details" />
    </table> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="details">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="descr_en"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Amt"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

While making a few assumptions about your full XML document, the benefit here is there's no need to make a for loop for each child of `<BS0900_summary_block>` (the assumption here being that `<BS0900_summary_block>` is always present).

Comment: many thks, let me try your suggestion today and "validate" your answer!